# using zookeeper to execute one by one

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In a distributed system, 5 processes, using zookeeper to coordinate.
I need these processes to run one by one in every round.
run order is dynamic, but is known for every round.

Any zookeeper recipe can do this? Thanks

for example:
round 1: 1 2 3 4 5
round 2: 3 2 4 1 5

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not fully defined:

1. In a situation when a given process fails to start do we have any kind of a timeout or does the system just halt?
2. Do the processes terminate between rounds, so that they are started by some external mechanism for every round?
3. Do we care about process termination status? If a process started but then failed in the middle of the execution, should the next process start?

In the simplest case, when we

- accept halting
- don't differentiate between a successful termination and a failure
- assume that every process is somehow started for every round and knows its position in the current round

we could use the following approach (probably can be simplified):

1. For a given round either pre-setup or make the first process in the round create a path `/round`.
2. The first process

   - checks that `getChildren('/round')` returns an empty list
   - creates an ephemeral znode `/round/exec_1`
   - creates a permanent znode `/round/start_1`
3. Every other process number `N`

   - gets the list of `/round`'s children
   - checks if `/round/start_{N-1}` exists
   - if yes, then checks `/round/exec_{N-1}` and waits for it to be deleted (using watcher)
   - if not, wait for it to appear (using watcher), then act as if the node was already there.

If the answers to the questions above are different, this protocol can be adjusted.

But the general idea here is to define how we indicate that a process is good to go: we register the fact that a previous process has started and then wait for it to terminate.